# WKWebView load files from both Bundle and Document directory

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

I am running a webapp using WKWebView which load content and assets (html, js, img, css...) from a Bundle directory called **Web_Assets**.

I proceed like this to load index.html, and set **Web_assets** as baseURL:

```
if let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource:"index", ofType:"html", inDirectory: "Web_Assets") { 
    let html = try String(contentsOfFile: filePath, encoding: .utf8)
    webView.loadHTMLString(html, baseURL: Bundle.main.resourceURL?.appendingPathComponent("Web_Assets"))
}
```

This works perfectly: index.html is loaded and Web_Assets serve as base path for other ressources without any problem.
I could also use the loadFileURL method which is equivalent (to my understanding).

BUT, now i'd like to use other ressources (video in my case) inside my WKWebView from the **Document** directory which is static and manageable via iTunes File Sharing, while of course keeping the present architecture as it is (Web assets inside Bundle directory).

For example my page index.html would load his style.css and other assets from **Web_Assets** and display an HTML5 video located in **Document**

Is it possible to do this ?

Ideas (which i don't know how to achieve):

1. Symlink of Document in Web_assets ?
2. Different baseURL for different file types in WKWebView ?
   (route all requests to Web_Assets except for mp4 files requests which are routed to Document)

Thanks for your help !

**EDIT 1:** 
Idea 1 is not possible since Bundle directories are read-only. 
Document can't be symlinked in Web_assets.
I can't manage to symlink Web_assets into Document either (weird error).
So i decided for now to copy Web_assets inside Document on each boot, so my Document folder can act as baseURL with my videos and web assets altogether.

It's a bit dirty since all my web assets are now visible in my Document folder (but not modifiable since the folder is erased and copied from Bundle uppon App restart)

Comment: you should use `URLRequest` and load it into your `webview`

Comment: sorry i don't see how i should use URLRequest.. could you elaborate a bit ? Thanks !

Comment: it's same same as you did: `if let fileURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "index", withExtension: "html", subdirectory: "Web_Assets") { webView.load(URLRequest(url: fileURL)) }`

Comment: ok so this way it doesn't set a baseURL right ? so how do i access my Document folder from insde de webview ?

Comment: How can you access assets in Document folder from a html page which loaded from Bundle ☹️, this sounds impossible. You can `copy` your webpage from Bundle to Document folder, then you load it from the Document folder, this is a better way.

Comment: yeah this is what i am working on. i was wondering if there was an advanced "routing" available to specify different baseURL regarding the request but WKWebView is not intended as an advanced router i guess :)

Comment: Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally end up as EDIT 1 and @ngbaanh suggested:

- on viewDidLoad:

  ```
  let filemgr = FileManager.default
  docURL = filemgr.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
  destPath = docURL.path+"/www/"
  sourcePath = Bundle.main.resourceURL!.appendingPathComponent("Web_Assets").path

  //COPY Web_Assets content from Bundle to Documents/www
  do {
      try filemgr.removeItem(atPath: destPath)
  } catch {
      print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
  }
  do {
      try filemgr.copyItem(atPath: sourcePath, toPath: destPath)
  } catch {
      print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
  }

  // Configure Webview
  webView.navigationDelegate = self
  webView.configuration.userContentController.add(self, name: "teleco")
  do {
     let baseURL = try filemgr.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor:nil, create:false)
     let fileURL = baseURL.appendingPathComponent("www/index.html")
     self.loadFileURL(fileURL, allowingReadAccessTo: baseURL)
  } catch {
     print(error)
  }
  ```

This way my baseURL is **Documents/www/**
So in my index.html i can include ressources like style.css

AND i can also access files in **Documents/** by using relative path like **../video.mp4**

So index.html and style.css are distributed via the Bundle, copied to Documents at runtime, which allows me to access Documents files too.

A bit twisted, but works great.

Downside: it exposes Web_assets files in user accessible Documents folder.
But they can't be altered since they are replaced on App start.

Comment: yeah, congrats  Thank you for expanding my little reply above.